# is environment file in angular secure?

Tags: angular, security

I am using Angular 15 . I have added some secret key ( like password and secret-key for encryption )
to environment file in angular . my question is NOT about security of environment file in Repository ( like git or etc ) . my question is about security of environment file in run-time (after deployment). I think environment file is not secure . is it correct ?

Is there a secure way for secrect-key in angular ?

Comment: There's no way to store secrets in a client-side app - it's running in your users' browsers, they have access to all the code in the bundle. Secrets need to be kept _server-side_.

Comment: yes , I guessed but I wanted to make sure in angular . Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to store secrets in a client-side app - it's running in your users' browsers, they have access to all the code in the bundle. Secrets need to be kept server-side.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer is a bit misleading. You can prevent your secrets from being sent to the client using a custom-webpack. This limits the types of secrets you can use however.  When using a custom-webpack you consume the secret on the server side and then pack up the output, without sending the secret to the client.  This makes it good for things like feature flags and environment settings that you might be hosting in a cloud app configuration store like AWS or AzureAppConfig.  You don't have to expose the readonly key to the client in this case which prevents the client from being able to read your config store (not a huge deal usually but it is something as hitting the config store drives up cloud costs).

One thing you cannot use it for are API keys that are consumed in your client side app though. You should use your back-end for this (and frankly most things involving secrets). So your angular client should authenticate with your backend using whichever method you choose, and the your back-end holds the secret and consumes it when the client requests something and returns the result.

There are of course other front-end frameworks that do more the work in the back-end like turbo etc.